# How to remove bookmark icon from jQuery upvote?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery upvote plugin from [here](http://janosgyerik.github.io/jquery-upvote/). I am using them to rate comments in a discussion. However, I don't want the users to bookmark the comments (rather they should be able to bookmark discussion itself). I am able to implement the voting mechanism, just that I am not able to remove the redundant star icon for 'bookmark' in the widgets that appear on every comment.

Any help in removing that icon and just keep the upvote, count and downvote parts will be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, just got to remove the `<a class="star"></a>` from HTML code!